# How can I reset password in Exchange with C #

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I cannot reset the active directory password from C #, I have this code

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path, dominio + @"\" + usu, pass1, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
try
{
    string strFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(sAMAccountName="+nameid+")))";
    ds.Filter = strFilter;
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("DistinguishedName");
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("CN");
    SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();
    string dn = result.Properties["DistinguishedName"][0].ToString();

    var user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
    user.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { oldpassword, newpassword });
    user.CommitChanges();

    MessageBox.Show("ok");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("error");
}
```

it works correctly, up to the line of INVOKE, that's when I get an error

```
user.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { oldpassword, newpassword });
```

Comment: Could you please add the error message you receive?

Comment: in english: ""An exception occurred in the invocation destination.""

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Active directory - exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901921/active-directory-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation)

Comment: I suspect this is a permissions issue like in the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Hello friends, I was able to solve the problem, with windows server 2003 does not allow Invoke, migrate to windows server 2012 and with the same code it works perfectly.

thanks to everyone